# How to join output of two commands in one line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

For example, following commands (in Windows 7):

```
date/t>>t.txt
time/t>>t.txt
```

create following lines in t.txt:

```
Fri 06/12/2015 
01:37 PM
```

Is it possible to join output of two commands (see above) in one line (see below)?

```
Fri 06/12/2015 01:37 PM
```

The above mentioned goal can be reached by command:

```
echo %date% %time%
```

But it is not an answer on this question, because this question is not about only above commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any number of commands, in a simpler way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "output="
for %%a in ("date /t" "time /t" "echo Hello world") do (
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('%%~a') do set "output=!output! %%b"
)
echo %output:~1%>> t.txt
```

Comment: Sorry @Aachi, but
if for /F "delims=" %%b in ('%%~a') do set "output=!output! %%b"
then there is extra space after 2015: "Mon 06/15/2015  08:41 AM"
and if for /F "delims=" %%b in ('%%~a') do set "output=!output!%%b"
then there is missed letter: "on 06/15/2015 08:42 AM"

Comment: I asummed you want each output separated by space as in your `echo %date% %time%` example! The first additional space is eliminated in the ":~1" part of `echo %output:~1%>> t.txt`. If you want not separation spaces, also change the last line by `echo %output%>> t.txt`

Comment: @Aachi: Yes, one space is needed. However, if You will see source of this page, then after "2015" You will see not one, but two spaces (whose changed to one spaces by browser).

Comment: I meant after "2015" in previous comment.

Comment: But, anyway, thanks! Because with `"output=!output!%%b"` and `echo %output:~0%>> t.txt` Your code works as needed too.

Comment: yep, but with `~0` it is more demonstrative :)

Answer (score 0):

The output of two commands can be joined in one line by using following commands (in batch file):

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('date/t') do set d=%%x
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('time/t') do set t=%%x
echo %d%%t%>>t.txt
```

Comment: Thanks to Joey (joey) and Frank Bollack (frank-bollack)! ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425807/redirecting-output-to-a-command-line-argument-of-another-command-in-windows )

Answer (score 0):

The output of two commands can be joined in one line also by using following commands (in batch file):

```
date /t>t_t.txt
set /p t=<t_t.txt
time /t>t_d.txt
set /p d=<t_d.txt
echo %t%%d%>>t.txt
```

Comment: Thanks to Stefanos Kalantzis (stefanos-kalantzis)! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568941/reading-the-content-of-a-text-file-into-an-environment-variable