# Node Package - Is it possible to interpolate a variable in package.json?

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs, command-line-interface

I have a static site that compile Sass using `node-sass`.

Currently I'm using Grunt to watch the file, but I feel it's overkill because I can use their built-in CLI.

So I add this in my package.json:

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "sass": "node-sass -w input/dir -o output-dir/" 
}
```

The problem is, I need to `require` a Sass framework module (installed globally) in the `--include-path`. I can do this in Gruntfile:

```
// Gruntfile.js
sass: {
  options: {
    includePaths: require("the-framework").includePaths()
  },
  ...
},
```

So the first thing that come to my mind is to interpolate the string like:

```
// package.json
...
"scripts": {
  "sass": "node-sass -w input/dir -o output-dir/ --include-path " + require("the-framework").includePaths()
}
```

And as expected, it doesn't work. Well the script runs, but the interpolated variable is ignored.

Any solution or alternative? If possible, I would prefer **not to create additional file** just to store the variable.

Thanks

Comment: SO editorial practices are such that answers must be posted as *answers*, not as edits to questions. Please post your answer as an actual answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know is it a right way to do it, but I can explain how I will would solve this task.

You cant interpolate variables in `package.json`, cause it must be valid json. That you can is to write bash commands here.

1) You can write node command that will needed result. You should take care if `includePaths()` does not return string.

```
Node options:
  -e, --eval script     evaluate script
  -p, --print           evaluate script and print result
```

So it would be something like

```
node -e "console.log(require('the-framework').includePaths())"
```

Or shorter version with `--print`

```
node -p "require('the-framework').includePaths()"
```

2) Inline output of previous command into sass script. Take care of right escaping.

```
{
  "scripts": {
      "sass": "node-sass -w input/dir -o output-dir/ --include-path $(node -p \"require('the-framework').includePaths()\")"
  }
}
```

More info about executing bash command you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).

P.S. Windows version differs

```
{
  "scripts": {
      "sass": "FOR /f \"delims=\" %v IN ('node -p \"require('edje').includePaths()[0]\"') DO node-sass -w assets/sass -o assets/css --include-path \"%v\""
  }
}
```

More info you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1425862/2044355).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think there's a mistake with the `$(...)`. I tried typing `node -p ...` in console and it successfully prints the path. But it doesn't work inside the `$(...)`.

Comment: I cant check it, cause I havent running example, but i try it with command ``ls -$(node -p "'la'")`` and it work exactly as ``ls -la``

Comment: no it doesn't, I get `ls: invalid option -- $`. I'm on Windows 10, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Ooops, i think windows version can be different. Im used Cygwin at windows always

Comment: I tried the `ls -$(...)` in Mac and it works. But I still need to make working code for windows

Comment: Yes, that works. Here's my final code, you can edit your answer and I will accept it: `FOR /f \"delims=\" %v IN ('node -p \"require('edje').includePaths()[0]\"') DO node-sass -w assets/sass -o assets/css --include-path \"%v\"`

Answer (score 0):

You can something like this:

```
“scripts”: {
  “sass”: “node-sass --include-path scss scss/main.scss   public/css/main.css”
},
```

Comment: The framework is a npm module and resides on the node installation directory, not within the project. I can get the path by using `require` but package.json doesn't allow string interpolation

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could solve this with npm scripts.

The first one that comes to my mind by looking at your specific need is, npm accepts extra parameters when calling a script. For example:

```
npm run sass -- path/to/the-framework
```

This will resolve to:

```
node-sass -w input/dir -o output-dir/ --include-path path/to/the-framework
```

---

Another way would be to move your code in a `.js` executable file (Node), let's call it `watch-sass.js`.

So your script will look like:

```
"sass": "node watch-sass.js"
```

And you would run:

```
npm run sass
```

This way you have much more freedom to do anything you want in your file.

---

Possibilities are infinite really, you could leverage the power of bash script instead of JS if you want, they can all read/write environment variables. But you don't necessarily need them. For instance you could just have a shell script that writes a package.json for you (or Python, or Ruby...), with all the variables already in place. But in the end I think it's just a matter of taste, use what you find simpler or more comfortable to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to avoid hardcoding the path, also I'm trying to do this without creating additional file (if not possible, then I will use the `.js` executable).

Comment: @DarcCode have you tried the first approach? I think it's possibly what you're looking for?

Comment: I don't want to type in `C::/ProgramFiles/.../...` everytime I want to run the script. Also the installation dir can be different between computer, so I need to use `require...`

Comment: How about passing in a relative path? Also it's not hardcoded, so in a different computer one would type a different path